# Hard Drive Partitioning in new Ubuntu studio

Tags: partitioning

I just installed ubuntu studio on my desktop computer. While installing I chose one drive and format everything.
Now I want to divide my partition in to three partitions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (with GUI) is to use [Gparted](https://gparted.org/).
To do it in CLI use **fdisk**. [Here is tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/) if you don't mind reading linux manual.

Comment: Thanks, but it wants pass and I can't enter the pass.

Comment: Boot from a live distro and repartition. The password to run gparted is your normal user password ( it runs as sudo ).